# CSV data set is getting executed before the JDBC sampler request

Tags: jmeter

1. I am performing login test with multiple concurrent users.

   2. I have created a JDBC request to get username and password from patient 
      table. and then Created a **Test.CSV** file using same data with the help of 
      BeanShell assertion.
   3. Now pass this file name in CSV dataset config**Test.csv**.
   4. I am able to login with multiple users concurrently but facing an issue:
      when I am running the test first time. The file is not available at the same location because it is being created after the execution of thread group.
      If file is not there I am getting this in log: **File Test.csv must exist and be readable**.

To execute the same process, What I am doing is, keeping the JDBC request is different test plan. Firstly executing that test plan and then proceeding to the login.

I want to execute and keep both requests is the same test plan.
one more thing If I am using the different thread group for these requests in the same test plan, Still facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Jmeter execution order is:-

0-Configuration elements

1-Pre-Processors

2-Timers

3-Sampler

4-Post-Processors (unless SampleResult is null)

5-Assertions (unless SampleResult is null)

6-Listeners (unless SampleResult is null)

Based on above, it is evident that "csv data config" will be executed first before the JDBC sampler.

What I can think of, if you want to get the username/pwd in the same Thread Group then you can set username and password as properties using  [__setProperty()](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__setProperty) and fetch it using [__property()](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__property). For this, use JSR223 Post Process after JDBC.
You can also use any of the other know post processor/scripting language, it is just groovy is better for performance test.

[Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that CSV Data Set Config is a [Configuration Element](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#config_elements) and according to test elements [Execution Order](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#executionorder) it is being initialised before anything else.

I would suggest going for [__CSVRead()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__CSVRead) function instead, JMeter functions are evaluated at the time they're being called so the Test.csv file will exist at the time you will be getting credentials from it. See [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-functions-introduction) to get familiarized with JMeter Functions concept.

Also be aware that according to JMeter Best Practices [it is recommended to switch to JSR223 Test Elements](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) from Beanshell or other scripting languages.